# How can I search a field as plaintext in ElasticSearch using Nest?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

The class i'm indexing looks like this:

```cs
Class ResData
{
    public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

I want to search the FullName field in a way similar to `string.contains`, not using token compare. I understand that it can be accomplished by marking the field with `[ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed)]`, but that does not seem to work. When I test it with `client.Analyze` I get a list of tokens, and searching `domo kun` does not match `domo kuny` but does match `kun domo`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By marking the field not_analyzed elasticsearch will take the field value **as is**. This is generally good for fields you want to sort on or do facetting on but not for full text search.

I would leave the standard analyzer and then try the `match_phrase_prefix` query:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that did work. However, to anyone reading this later on, if you want to search a field in ES like in string.contains, you're probably not approaching your problem right. I sure didn't.